# Prestashop changing employer data through webservice without changing the password

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Now in the prestashop administrative panel, you could leave the password area blank, and the password don’t change.

But with webservice I got problems because, if I send the empty string or a null the password changes anyway... :/
And I can't leave the password tag out, because is required.

The data I send:

```
{'prestashop':{
    'employee':{
        'id':'1',
        'id_lang':'1',
        'email':'test@test.te',
        'lastname':'Tset',
        'firstname':'Test',

        'passwd':null,

        'active':'1',
        'id_profile':'2',
        'bo_color':null,
        'default_tab':'1'
    }
}}
```

If anyone could help, please :)

Comment: And I'm using PrestaShop™ 1.5.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to send same password again. Web service is weird in many cases, but I still love it.

Comment: yes, but I don't know the password(only the hashed one), cause I get the data from webservice :/
and if I send the hashed password, it hashes again, and is not the same anymore :(

Comment: Thats weird, I will try to find out a solution with trial.

Comment: woww mann, actualy it WORKS!!!! :D if you post the hashed password, the password in the DB, I had an error in the code where I was retrieving the data... :/
Thx you very very much! :D